# Adding a custom class to the jquery datepicker prev/next options

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am working on an integration and I need to add a class into the datepicker ".ui-datepicker-next" and ".ui-datepicker-prev" options. So when the calendar is rendered the prev/next buttons have a class called "no-pjax".

I've tried beforeShow, beforeShowDays.. nothing seems to work

```
            var from = $(this).find(".from").datepicker({
                  defaultDate: "+1w",
                  changeMonth: true,
                  numberOfMonths: 1,
                  beforeShow : function(){
                    console.log("before");
                  }
                })
                .on( "change", function() {
                  to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
                });

            var to = $(this).find(".to").datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                beforeShow : function(){
                    console.log("before");
                }
              })
              .on( "change", function() {
                from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
              });





        $('.ui-datepicker-next').on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
            //$(this).addClass("no-pjax");
        });

        $('.ui-datepicker-prev').on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
            //$(this).addClass("no-pjax");
        });
```

Comment: so add class after show then...

Comment: that doesn't work - doesn't even seem to be invoked. I think also that as you alternate between the months - it would fire a different function as such

Comment: -- if on click trying to add the class at that point before invoking the action may work - but similar problem with initializing.

Comment: `$(this).addClass("no-pjax");` should be before `return false`

Answer (score 0):

Well as You are using jQuery You can do something like that:

```
setTimeOut(function(){
   $('.ui-datepicker-prev').addClass('.no-pjax');
  $('.ui-datepicker-next').addClass('.no-pjax');
},200);
```

set the delay time (200 ms) so it will work well for You

Comment: Sloppy - but won't always work when clicking on different months

Comment: if you will add this function inside $('.ui-datepicker-next/prev').on("click" .... it would work i guess.

Comment: ^ yeah - its about invoking that piece of js -- when the calendar gets re-rendered - which happens when you pop it up - and click on toggling the prev/next